# Deactivating a Salesforce.com System Administrator w/o Breaking the System

Tags: admin

I wanted to Deactivate a System Administrator.
That particular user have some scheduled tasks.
can i deactivate him or change his Profile/Role.

I want to deactivate because of limited licenses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to his User page and unclick Active. This will keep his set up but he will not be able to log in or use SFDC. By doing this you will get his SFDC licence that you can assign to someone else.
You should check that he is not connected to any thing that can give you problems. Like dynamic reports for example.